# FreeBSD ZFS raidz1 Started a (da59) drive replacement. During resilver, second drive (da60) failed

Tags: raid, storage, freebsd, zfs, redundancy

Our system started slowing down... Found a couple of drives in the same raid that looked scary.
Replaced the drive that S.M.A.R.T. marked as failure eminent. (da59)

Then da60 started to error.
Finally the system marked it "removed".

da59 was working before the replacement

Is there a way to start over? Stop or offline the replacement process,
force the original da59 back online, then replace drive (da60) that must have been
worse off then da59?

Code:

```
      raidz1-7                 DEGRADED 14.2K     0 12.2K
        da56                   ONLINE       0     0     0
        da57                   ONLINE       0     0     0
        da58                   ONLINE       0     0     0
        replacing-3            DEGRADED 14.2K     0     0
          1386012792062170018  OFFLINE      0     0     0  was /dev/da59/old
          da59                 ONLINE       0     0     0  (resilvering)
        13092123056171323448   REMOVED      0     0     0  was /dev/da60
        da61                   ONLINE       0     0     0
        da62                   ONLINE       0     0     0
        da63                   ONLINE       0     0     0
```

The zpool's name is tank

Here's my command plan,

zpool online tank 13092123056171323448 da60

zpool clear tank da60

watch status to see da60 online

then:
zpool offline tank replacing-3

once offline, pull "new" da59 and insert "old" da59
wait to see if the system recognizes "old" da59

then:
zpool online tank 1386012792062170018 da59

once da59 is online, if replacing-3 is still present

then:
zpool detach replacing-3

assuming the system is feeling better

then:
zpool offline tank da60

pull "old" da60 drive and insert "new" da60
wait for it to be recognized

then:
zpool replace tank 13092123056171323448 da60

Hopefully there is enough life in "old" da59 to allow for
new da60 to resilver....

Is there merit in my idea?
Thanks, - Jon

Comment: I am no expert, but the way I understand it...in a Z1, you can only afford to lose 1 drive...anything >1 costs you the entire pool.

Comment: Yup, thats why I want to set the not-to-good da60 online before I stop the replacing-3 process... I just need to know if my command things are correct... Hoping to find an expert!!! hahaha thanks!